# How to find angle between two vectors on canvas?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

I need to find the angle between two vectors on my canvas.
I have attached some examples below:
[image]

[image]

Could you advise me some formula? I have problems with school math :)

Comment: Is it a vector or a  segment?

Comment: I have the beginning point of each line, so I guess it is a vector

Comment: So is 5''0' and 4''3' their length? Or are those coordinates?

Comment: It is their length.

Comment: So where's the 0 coordinate on the picture?

Comment: On the left top corner of the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need to make the point which connects your two vectors the origin, where x=0 and y=0.

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

Now we can say that the x and y values of the points **A**, **B** and **C** are:

- A = 0|0
- B = 0|-6
- C = 5|2

To calculate the arctangent of both we can utilize the **Math.atan2()** function. Please note that the first parameter for atan2 must be the y value.

```
var firstAngle = Math.atan2(-6, 0);
var secondAngle = Math.atan2(2, 5);
```

and get the difference of them by subtraction

```
var angle = secondAngle - firstAngle;
```

This will return a radian value you can convert to degrees like this:

```
angle = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: 0|-6 and 5|2 are not points, but length. But it doesn't matter.
I will try and comment. Thank you!

Comment: I used this formula, but when I built the shape like the first picture I got 0. But the real angle is 90.

Comment: If I use -5|0 for the point top-left and 0|5 for the bottom-right I get 90 degrees - as expected.

Comment: For C 5|2 are not the correct coordinates. That is the length.

Comment: Don't get confused I'm not talking about the length (which is the magnitude of a vector). I'm talking about the direction from the center point A. In my answer above you have to travel 5 blocks to the right and ~2 blocks down to get from point A to point C -> that's the vector. It's just a coincidence that the length in your picture says 5" 2' too.

Comment: So, the length of vector (5,2) will be sqrt (5*5 + 2*2), right? which is 5.38.

Comment: So, it is not a vector with coordinates (5,2)

Comment: Well a vector doesn't have coordinates - it's has a direction (from a relative position). That relative position is point A and to get to point C you have to move 5 blocks right, 2 blocks down thus 5|2. Likewise with point B - you have to move 6 blocks up (-6) and don't need to move horizontally (0).

Comment: And from that relative position, the vector would be (5,2). If we accept that point A is (0,0). Then, calculating the length of that vector by the formula above - the length of the vector on the picture - does not match. I assume that the pictures in the question are not very exact. If you look closer, point C doesn't really reach a corner.

Comment: Yes, it's more like 4.9|1.8 but I wanted to simplify things by using integers

Comment: I guess I know what is the issue. Point A doesn't have coordinates (0,0)
I will describe the data of the picture.
B - (180, 30)
A - (180, 210)
C - (330, 270)

0, 0 coordinates on the left right corner of the screen.

Comment: To make a point origin (0,0) - which should be point A in our example - you have to subtract it's position from all other points. So if those are A(180,210) B(180,30) C(330,270) do B.x-A.x B.y-A.y to get (0,-180) and C.x-A.x C.y-A.y to get (150,60). Now do the calculation in my answer again with those values.

Comment: I don't think this answer is quite correct. If I use this formula with points (x=-1, y=1) and (x=-1, y=-1), I get 270 (or -270 if the parameters are inverted), but the angle between these vectors is 90.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to **normalize** the two vectors.

Once that's done you can do

```
angle = arcos(v1•v2)
```

where "angle" is the angle you want to find, "arcos" is the inverse of cosine function and the "•" is the dot product operator

**Be careful, this will return only the relative and raw angle. You won't be able to know which vector is on the left and which one is on the right.**

Comment: how to calculate this v1 * v2?

V1 and V2 are consists of two points.

Comment: This works even if you don't normalize it.  You can know left from right if you use the right hand rule: take the cross product.  The sign tells you left or right.

Answer (score 1):

If you need **2D** (`z=0`) and **3D** support, you could use the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

```js
const dot = (p1, p2) => p1.x * p2.x + p1.y * p2.y + p1.z * p2.z;
```

With a square magnitude (`magSq`), we can calc the magnitude: `mag = Math.sqrt(magSq)`

```js
const magSq = ({x, y, z}) => x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2;
const mag = Math.sqrt(magSq(p));
```

Now we can calc the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and "normalize" it afterwards.
Now use `acos()` to get the angle:

```
const angle = Math.acos(dot(p1, p2) / Math.sqrt(magSq(p1) * magSq(p2)));
```

We could also use [`Math.hypot()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot), a dedicated JS function for `mag`:

```
const mag = (p) => Math.hypot(p.x, p.y, p.z);
```

… and get the angle:

```
const angle = Math.acos(dot(p1, p2) / (mag(p1) * mag(p2)));
```

#### Example:

```js
let a = {x: 0, y: -6, z: 0};
let b = {x: 5, y: 2, z: 0}; // set z != 0 for 3D

let dot = (p1, p2)=>  p1.x * p2.x + p1.y * p2.y + p1.z * p2.z;
let magSq = ({x, y, z}) => x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2;

let angle1 = Math.acos(dot(a, b) / Math.sqrt(magSq(a) * magSq(b)));
console.log('1. Angle:', angle1);                                        // 1.9513027

// ... or
let mag = ({x, y, z}) => Math.hypot(x, y, z);

let angle2 = Math.acos(dot(a, b) / (mag(a) * mag(b)))
console.log('2. Angle:', angle2);                                        // 1.9513027
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question. But I found good solution. Let say we have 4 points form 2 vectors. Points (P0, P1, P2, P3), then the angle of P0P1 and P2P3 is:

```
function angle2Vectors(ps) {
  const v1 = { x: ps[1].x - ps[0].x, y: ps[1].y - ps[0].y };
  const v2 = { x: ps[3].x - ps[2].x, y: ps[3].y - ps[2].y };
  const l1_l2 = len(ps[1], ps[0]) * len(ps[3], ps[2]);
  const v1_v2 = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
  const cos = v1_v2 / (len(ps[1], ps[0]) * len(ps[3], ps[2]));
  const angCos = Math.acos(cos) * (180 / Math.PI);
  const _v1_v2_ = v1.x * v2.y - v2.x * v1.y;
  const sin = _v1_v2_ / l1_l2;
  const angSin = Math.asin(sin) * (180 / Math.PI);
  return angCos * Math.sign(angSin);
}
```